# Copy merged cells from other sheets into one cell in summary sheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I have a workbook which has a Summary Sheet and updates with new sheets (with changing names, imported from a specified path) upon command. In the summary sheet, I want to collect specific information present in the other sheets (all of them have the same template filled in with different information).

For example, I want to copy the merged ranges `B3:O3` in Sheet `X`, Sheet `Y` and Sheet `Z` into Cells `A2, B2, C2` in Summary Sheet.

Questions:

A) How do I copy the info?

B) How do I link the command to existing "Refresh Sheets" command which populates the workbook with updated information from a specified folder?

Relatively new to VBA, so excuse me if question is basic. Thanks!

Comment: You take the top left cell of each merged area.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to refresh the sheet?

Comment: Record a macro, and see what the VBA code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `B3:O3` is a merged range you take the top left cell from each. `Sub RefreshSheets` represents your existing command and then there is a call within that code to the new sub `GetInfo`.

Like this

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RefreshSheets()

    'Your current refresh code
     GetInfo  'call to other sub

End Sub

Public Sub GetInfo()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

With wb.Worksheets("Summary Sheet")

   .Range("A2") = wb.Worksheets("X").Range("B3")
   .Range("B2") = wb.Worksheets("Y").Range("B3")
   .Range("C2") = wb.Worksheets("Z").Range("B3")

End With


End Sub
```

If working with variable sheet names you could assign by position e.g.

```
Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

Or use a variable

```
Dim X As String
X = "X"

Sheets(X)
```

Comment: Appreciate it. The limitation is that Sheet Names are constantly changing upon refresh (depends on what is in the pre-specified folder). Therefore I cannot tie the copy command to the sheet name and was looking for alternatives.

Comment: Can you do it by sheet index? I.e. the position of the newly added sheets?

Comment: Sheets(Sheet.Count) for last sheet for example?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that. As mentioned, I am a novice. Could you help by resending the whole code?

Comment: Is your code adding new sheets? Or renaming existing sheets?  Are you always updating range A2:C2 with values from 3 newly added sheets?

Comment: When you add 3 new sheets if they are added to the end then they will be at positions Sheets(Sheets.Count),  Sheets(Sheets.Count-1) and  Sheets(Sheets.Count-2) But when you add them you could assign them to a worksheet variable e.g. Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of sheet in other book")  then do   .Range("A2") = ws.Worksheets("X").Range("B3")

Comment: Without seeing more code it is difficult to advice you effectively